# ElastiCache cloudwatch metrics for Redis: currItems for a single database

Tags: redis, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elasticache

I have set up a metric for the aws interface on the ElastiCache redis cluster. I'm looking at a value of currItems superior to a certain number for a given period (say 1000 for 1 minute)

The issue I have is that I have two databases in Redis, name 0 and 1. I would like to only get the currItems for database 0, not database 1, since database 1 is holding values for a longer period of time and make the whole metric look much bigger than it should be (since I want the current items of database 0)

Is there a way to create a metric that would only get the currItems of the database 0?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an application for this or use existing redis tools.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614737/what-are-some-recommended-tools-to-monitor-a-redis-database

[If you are using new relic](https://newrelic.com/plugins/meetme-inc/28?utm_source=GOOG&utm_medium=paid_search&utm_content=Redis&utm_campaign=Redis&utm_term=Redis&mpc=PS-GOOG-Platform-Redis-EN-SIGNUP-APAC-Redistroubleshooting-Redis&_kk=redis%20tools&_kt=8c73f104-f4e7-4f37-ac51-768a6e8839ac)